# Convert 2 types of date strings to datetime objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a reliable way to convert formatted date strings into datetime objects so I can save into the database. I'm importing data from an RSS feed and the date strings look like this `10/31/2012 11:59:00 PM`, but every once in a while one will come through with no time data, like this: `9/24/2012`. Is there a way to convert the string to a datetime object regardless if the time is present or not?

I was using `Date.strptime()` because `Date.parse()` wasn't being reliable enough for me. Here's what I was using, which will error out when it encounters the date string without the time.

```
Date.strptime(i.xpath('activedate').text, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').to_datetime
```

What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic):

```
require 'chronic'

Chronic.parse '10/31/2012 11:59:00 PM'
#=> 2012-10-31 23:59:00 0800
Chronic.parse '9/24/2012'
#=> 2012-09-24 12:00:00 0800
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just loop through an array of the possible date formats and try parsing until one succeeds:

```
parsed_date = nil

['%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', '%m/%d/%Y'].each do |format|
  parsed_date ||= DateTime.strptime(i.xpath('activedate').text, format) rescue nil
end
```